# how to get specific data in array field in a document in mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongodb-query

example:

```
user {  
   "_id":ObjectId("597c9fabc1ada32277f1da34"),
   "fname":"Neel",
   "lname":"Path",
   "username":"nev"   "following":[  
      {  
         "fname":"Him",
         "lname":"Madhu",
         "username":"him"
      },
      {  
         "fname":"Ron",
         "lname":"Lak",
         "username":"ron"
      }
   ]
}
```

i want to get only the usernames included in array field called following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
db.getCollection('user').find({'fname':'Neel'}, {following: 1, _id: 0}).pretty();
```

Comment: why did you remove answer

Comment: sry, im new in stackoverflow.
anyway i go an error called  'db.getCollection is not a function'

Comment: again you unmarked. if you are using mongoose. use model.find()

Comment: then it should be db.usercollection.find()

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple..

To get all the users with field `username` which is inside an array named `following`.

`db.getCollection('user').find({}, {'following.username': 1}).pretty();`

**OR**

To get specific suer with field `username` which is inside an array named `following`.

`db.getCollection('user').find({"_id":ObjectId("597c9fabc1ada32277f1da34")}, {'following.username': 1}).pretty();`

Comment: but, i got an error called 'db.getCollection is not a function'? :(

Comment: From where you are making a request to your db.

Comment: im using mongojs and in server(nodejs expressjs)